# What's the difference between following properties C#

Tags: c#, properties

I am using these two properties

1)

```
int x = 0;

public int X
{
    get
    {
        return x;
    }
    set
    {
        x = value;
    }
}
```

2)

```
 public string ID
 {
     get;
     set;
 }
```

what's the difference between these two properties.

Comment: Check this out:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 2):

> When you declare a property as shown in the following example, the
>   **compiler creates a private, anonymous backing field** that can only be
>   accessed through the property's get and set accessors.

[Auto-Implemented Properties (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)

The only difference is a fact, that in your example you're still able to get/set backing field directly, instead of using the property. With auto-implemented properties you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Both are same, except you can do this from the first snippet which second snippet can't do.

```
int x = 0;

public int X
{
    get
    {
        return x;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value < 0) // A guard condition or some custom condition here
            value = 0;

        x = value;
    }
}
```

For a more clear answer you can do

```
private double seconds;

public double Hours
{
    get { return seconds / 3600; }
    set { seconds = value * 3600; }
}
```

Comment: then what's the difference between a simple variable and second snippet.

Comment: What you did in first is automatically done by compiler in second. However if you want to control the value of local variable and property when value is set and extracted you can use the snippet as I wrote in my answer.